# Path problem in civicrm under wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Using .htaccess to put Wordpress in its own directory.  Problem is that civicrm was installed using the subdirectory after the domain name.  I try to update the path and wordpress logs out.  Anything I try to do with Civicrm logs me out of Wordpress.  I can't seem to get around this problem.  If I edit my settings file, civicrm will not work.

Comment: Have you edited your civicrm.settings.php file?  If that's the "settings file" you're referring to, could you explain what settings changes you made?

Comment: Yes, I had to change the path to the subdirectory where the Wordpress installation was in order to upgrade.  However, I have .htaccess files in the root and subdirectories as documented in the help files for putting Wordpress in its own directory.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, CiviCRM does not work if WordPress is [installed in its own directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) rather than the default location.  I have not tested this recently, but

- I know it did not work in the initial versions of CiviCRM for WordPress,
- I haven't heard about any change to this, and
- I haven't had any reason to have WordPress in its own directory.

Notes in [CRM-16421](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16421) also indicate that it's still an issue as of 4.6.

My advice is to get WordPress back out of its own directory and try again.  It may not be your preference, but it's what works.

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I did.  I also had to reinstall civicrm, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a file permission problem... did you copy the files yourself?

You need to make sure the paths are correct (do this with the configuration file instead of the database...)

Then check the file owners and permissions in your new directory structure... The directories would be 755 and the files 644... for this to work the file owners should be the web server ...

Hope this helps...

Comment: All ot those things are correct.  I believe that civicrm is not checking the right setting to find the files so it doesn't think the user is logged into wordpress.

Comment: I believe this to be a bug in civicrm.  How can I log the bug or escalate this to get eyeballs looking at it . #Jon

Comment: Hmm... I run my sites in the root on production servers and in sub directories in my test environment as I am running a few... This only happens when your paths are set wrong in the database...

You can set those paths in the civicrm.settings.php which is in your civicrm directory... Those paths will override the database values so you can keep those settings local if you have a couple of installs (dev and prod for example...)...

Try to set those to the exact path and see if that solves your problems, if so, it was a path in the database that was still wrong...

Comment: Thanks Serge.  I must have had a bad path in the database.  I had to move my website out of the wordpress directory, then I had to reinstall civicrm and everything worked.